# algunos iconos de FontAwesome no se ven correctamente en nativescript-vue

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, icons, nativescript

hola estoy desarrollando una app móvil con nativescript-vue, en esta aplicación utilizo iconos de FontAwesome 5.3.1 con codigos cheatsheet el problema es que algunos iconos no se renderizan como deberían.

aca importo los estilos y fontawesome en el main.js de la app

```
import {TNSFontIcon, fonticon} from 'nativescript-fonticon';
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';

 TNSFontIcon.debug = true;
 TNSFontIcon.paths = {
  'fa': './font-awesome.css',
  'ion': './ionicons.css'
 };
 TNSFontIcon.loadCss();
  //vue ya e
 Vue.filter('fonticon', fonticon);
```

este icono por ejemplo se muestra

```
<Label class="section fa" border="1" textWrap="true" width="110" heigth="20" 
                      :text="'\uf155 80.000'" backgroundColor="#fcfcfc"  />
```

pero este por ejemplo que es el que esta en la fila deudas con fondo rojo tiene un simbolo raro

```
<Label class="section fa" textWrap="true" width="165" heigth="20" 
                :text="'\uf54c Deudas'" backgroundColor="#ff5656" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el icono que no se muestra correctamente es este y no es el único son varios mas que no se visualizan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cual podría ser el problema?, para instalar FontAwesome use como ejemplo la documentación oficial de la pagina nativescript-vue https://nativescript-vue.org/blog/using-fonticons/

Comment: En la documentación, en los ejemplos usan filtros (Vue.filter('fonticon', fonticon)) para mostrar los iconos (:text="'fa-eye' | fonticon"). ¿Has probado a hacerlo con filtros?

Comment: @JaviMollá lo del fitro lo tengo , e intentado como esta en la documentacion pero no funciona (:text="'fa-eye' | fonticon")  en ves de eso uso :text="'\uf155 80.000'" con el codigo del icono

Comment: Lo único diferente que veo es que a un label le aplicas la clase fa y al otro no. Prueba a dejar los dos igual a ver. Otras cosas que puedes probar son: sacar el icono a un elemento separado (un span, por ejemplo), por ver si se visualiza solo o cambiar el texto que viene después del icono

Comment: lo hice sigue igual

Comment: ¿Has probado las dos opciones: ponerles la misma class y sacar el icono a un elemento separado como un span?

Comment: si probe las dos formas que mencionaste y obtengo el mismo resultado se ve ese simbolo extraño como arabe

Comment: Estoy viendo la documentación de nuevo y veo que para poner código y texto junto debes hacerlo de otro modo Prueba a poner `<Label class="section fa" textWrap="true" width="165" heigth="20" backgroundColor="#ff5656" />{{ 'fa-eye' | fonticon }} Deudas</Label>`

Comment: no funciona ni siquiera se muestra, podría ser un problema de codificación o la versión del SO de android?, aun asi es raro por que algunos iconos se ven y otros no. intentare correr la aplicacion en otro dispositivo a ver que pasa

Comment: @JaviMollá en un foro de github sale una persona igual que le aparece el mismo icono raro, podrias echarle un vistazo yo no entendi muy bien https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template/issues/24

Comment: Hay una respuesta que dice de cambiar la u por la f en el código utf. Escribir `\ff54c Deudas` en lugar de `\uf54c Deudas`

Comment: @JaviMollá lo intente y muestra el codigo como texto

Comment: yo probara toda las variantes posibles con los codigos pero creo que deberia ser  \f54c. como dice la doc